# Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer: can't set up OAuth client

Tags: java, spring-oauth2

For learning purposes, I've decided to create a sample application that would consist of three services (Java modules).

- OAuth 2 authorization server
- resource server
- OAuth 2 client

I've not had any big issues with the first 2 of them, but I've spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to create a valid OAuth 2 client, but I keep on receiving this error: `Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:9000"`.

Since I've no clue where the issue is, I'll provide all the neccessary context of all 3 services.

Here's the configuration of the **resource server**.

- `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: "http://localhost:9000"
          jwk-set-uri: "http://localhost:9000/oauth2/jwks"
```

- `SecurityConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
        return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
        http
                // SECURITY
                .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(headers -> headers
                        .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                // RISK
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/data-api/users")).denyAll()
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/data-api/users/**")).denyAll()
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/data-api/taco-orders")).denyAll()
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/data-api/taco-orders/**")).denyAll()
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.POST, "/data-api/tacos")).authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/data-api/tacos/**")).denyAll()
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.POST, "/data-api/ingredients")).hasAuthority("SCOPE_ingredients.write")
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/data-api/ingredients/**")).hasAuthority("SCOPE_ingredients.delete")
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/design"), mvc.pattern("/orders")).hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/"), mvc.pattern("/**")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .formLogin((formLogin) -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/design"));
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**Authorization server** settings...

- `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 9000
```

- `AuthServerConfig`

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("taco-cloud-client")
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantTypes(grantTypes -> grantTypes.addAll(Set.of(
                        AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
                        AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN
                )))
                .redirectUris(redirectUris -> redirectUris.addAll(Set.of(
                        "http://127.0.0.1:9090/authorized",
                        "http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/taco-cloud-client"
                )))
                .scopes(scopes -> scopes.addAll(Set.of(
                        "ingredients.write",
                        "ingredients.delete",
                        OidcScopes.OPENID
                )))
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    private static RSAKey generateRsa() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }
}
```

- `SecurityConfig`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And the problematic **OAuth 2.0 client**:

- `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          taco-cloud-client:
            provider: tacocloud
            client-id: taco-cloud-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - openid
              - ingredients.read
              - ingredients.write
        provider:
          tacocloud:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
```

- `SecurityConfig`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                        oauth2Login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/taco-cloud-client"))
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Uff.. That's it, I think ;D If anyone would be so kind to point me in the right direction, I'd be thankful!

Comment: Is the Authorization server started when before you start the client?

Comment: @ch4mp yes, yes

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the full log. However, I think this issue appears to be similar to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721352/could-not-extract-response-no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-response). Then you need to update your SecurityConfig of Authorization Server:

```
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(withDefaults());
    return http
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
  }
```