# Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type in springn oauth2client code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Im trying to implement spring security oauth2client.
Im using springboot 3. I have implemented the spring security oauth2 authorization server as well.
When I start the client application I get the `Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]`

Here is my application.yml configuration
server:
port: 8080

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/practice
    username: dbadmin
    password: Ph03nix5parr0w!
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
    dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          api-client-oidc:
            provider: spring
            client-id: api-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: opened
            client-name: api-client-oidc
          api-client-authorization-code:
            provider: spring
            client-id: api-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized"
            scope: api.read
            client-name: api-client-authorization-code
        provider:
          spring:
            issuer-uri: http://auth-server:9000
```

Here is my websecurity config class in the client application

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URLS = {
        "/hello",
        "register",
        "verifyRegistration*",
        "resendVerificationToken*",
        "savePassword",
        "resetPassword",
        "changePassword"
};

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
}

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(r -> r.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS).permitAll())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(r -> r.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/api-client-oidc"))
            .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
}
}
```

Here is the security config from the oauth2 authorization server

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

public DefaultSecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
    this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
}


@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}

@Autowired
public void bindAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
}
}
```

the complete exception is:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://auth-server:9000"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://auth-server:9000"
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.getBuilder(ClientRegistrations.java:228) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.fromIssuerLocation(ClientRegistrations.java:152) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper.getBuilderFromIssuerIfPossible(OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper.java:97) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper.getClientRegistration(OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper.java:71) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper.lambda$asClientRegistrations$0(OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper.asClientRegistrations(OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.clientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:124) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1149) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1132) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:882) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:731) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.lambda$oidc$0(ClientRegistrations.java:163) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.getBuilder(ClientRegistrations.java:216) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
... 87 common frames omitted
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Im able to run my oauth2 authorization server and perform the login operations.
Please help.

Comment: Are you sure your endpoint is the good one ? Maybe your pointing to a wrong endpoint and get some HTML from the backend-server and not expected JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue. In the end, it helped to modify oauth2 authorization server:

```
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(withDefaults());
    return http
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
  }
```

Comment: I already have set the highest precedence to the `OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration` filter configuration in the authorization server. It still does not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).